# Angular-5 App is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular5

I was clone repository of other developer, when I run npm start it shows  me an error in command line

> ERROR in Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify
>   either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule
>   to the plugins options.

Comment: There's probably a problem in the code somewhere.

Comment: **Please read `Readme.md` file of that repo**, you should do `npm install` before `npm start`

Comment: I already run npm install but still not working

Comment: its working now, actually there is a path error in main.ts

Comment: Is it a related error ? If not, you can close or solve this question

Comment: @NayoR the solution of the problem is in main.ts the import path of AppModule is specify wrong that is 

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

than I changed it to this 

import { AppModule } from './app/components/app/app.module';

and then it work